# closures: expected u32 found type parameter

Tags: rust

Soy nuevo en Rust

EL problema radica en que mi tipo generico T solo acepta argumentos de U32 y en este caso estoy intentando pasar un  valor generico que almaceno en U.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer cast a los genericos para pasarlos a un tipo en concreto? o que puedo hacer para solucionar el problema,

codigo:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cacher<T, U> where T: Fn(u32) -> u32 {
    calcular:T,
    valor:Option<U>,
}
impl<T, U> Cacher<T, U> where T: Fn(u32) -> u32 {
    fn nuevo(calcular:T, valor:U) -> Cacher<T, U> {
        Cacher{
            calcular,
            valor:None,
        }
    }
    fn valor(&mut self, arg:U) -> u32 {
        match self.valor {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calcular)(arg);
                self.valor = Some(arg);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

fn generar(intensidad:u32){
    let mut resultado = Cacher::nuevo(|num| {
        println!("Trabajando");
        num
    },None);

    let res_a = resultado.valor(Some(4));
}

fn main() {
    generar(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trata cambiar `resultado.valor(Some(4))` a `resultado.valor(4)`, para que `U` sea `u32` en vez de `Option<u32>`. También, el mezclaje de `U` y `u32` es problemática; es necesario siempre usar el uno o el otro si deben ser intercambiados, porque Rust no puede verificar que siempre son lo mismo. Si eso no funciona, explica porqué, y provee el mensaje de error entero.

Comment: Trata de explicar el porqué debería de hacer ese cambio, así tu respuesta estará más completa.